# Finding and comparing two objects, while avoiding NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, linq, null, boolean-expression

I am trying to compare an original object to an updated one to find if they are different from each other. The compare logic should be as follows:

- If neither object a nor b contains an object in SomeList, which has EType equal to EnumType.FooType, they should be evaluated as equals.
- If only a xor b contains an object in SomeList, which has EType equal to EnumType.FooType, they should be evaluated as different.
- If both objects contain an object as mentioned above, and the property Number is equal on both objects, then objects a and b should be evaluated as equals.

The following code solves the task, however it is long and bulky, so I ask if it can be shortened and made 'prettier'?

```
var a = original.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum);
var b = updated.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum);
var bEqual = false;
if (a == null && b == null)
    bEqual = true;
else if (a != null && b != null)
    bEqual = a.Number == b.Number;
```

Comment: The description of the problem compared to the code does not really match. You say that you *have* two objects, and then show code that tries to *find* two objects. Either way, if the code works you probably want to post it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Edited the title to include the 'finding' of objects. However, the goal is still to compare the two first objects a and b, although the comparison relies on objects they may or may not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (a == null) ? (b == null) :
    (b != null && a.Number == b.Number);
```

A better solution is to create a full set of equality functions and operators. This means implementing IEquatable and override Object.Equals(object). A total of four small functions would enable you to write:

```
return a == b;
```

MSDN has a good article about overriding equality functions.

[How to: Define Value Equality for a Type (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In C# 6.0 you can use the null propagation operator:

```
var a = original.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum);
var b = updated.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum);
return a?.Number == b?.Number;
```

Comment: Then if `a` is `null` and `b.Number` is null, this will return `true`.

Comment: This would be good, but we are currently not using C# 6.0, so I cannot do this yet.

Comment: I guess Number is an integer so won't be nullable - just a guess as we don't have all the information.

Comment: Number is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Well straight off the bat you can do this

```
 var a = original.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum);
 var b = updated.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum);
 var bEqual = false;
 if (a == null && b == null)
     bEqual = true;
 else
     bEqual = a.Number == b.Number;
```

You are already checking if they are null so if they are null then you are setting your bEqual to true; and if they aren't null then you can just perform the normal code below.

Now without testing your code I would think you could do something like this

```
 if(original.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum) != null && updated.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum) != null)
    bEqual = original.Number == updated.Number;
```

Something along those lines should be sufficient if I was at home I would test it for you and make sure but it should be close enough.

Comment: I don't think I can do a.Number == b.Number, because either a or b may be null. Also, original.Number and updated.Number will not work, since they do not have those properties directly.

Comment: I thought that about the second part, You should be able to do a.Number and b.Number you are already checking if they are null in the first if statement, if they are null it wont go into the else statement it will skip it, and if a and b == null returns false then they have to not be null, so it will do the else statement

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it with conditional operator :

```
var a = original.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum);
var b = updated.SomeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.EType == EnumType.FooEnum);
bool bEqual = (a == null && b == null)? true : 
                 (a != null && b != null)? a.Number == b.Number : false;
```

Comment: Yeah, that may be the only feasible thing to do, however it may hurt human readability.

Comment: This is the "if a is true then b is true else b is false" pattern, which is quite often used while people really meant "b = a"